# Is vCard 2.1 still in use?

Tags: webdav, vcf-vcard, carddav

Is vCard 2.1 format still used by any software? Does any software still generates contacts in this format or excepts it (as of October 2013)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outlook still uses that version.  Most other email applications seem to use version 3.0.

Comment: Thank you Michael. Also I have just verified that Outlook 2013 is still using vCard 2.1

Comment: Michael, are there any application that is using vCard v4.0? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499497/any-application-using-vcard-4-0